# Disable struts jquery dialog button on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I want to disable the Submit Doc button when the dialog is first loaded.. how can i do so?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<sj:dialog id="submitdialog" resizable="false" autoOpen="false" modal="true" width="800" height="440" 
buttons="{ 
                 
'Submit CAD':function() { submitOk(); },
                 
  'Cancel':function() { submitCancel(); } 
                 
}" title="Submit Document">
</sj:dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it so using jQuery. On opening of the dialog you can put this inside the document.ready function:

```js
$("#submitdialog").next(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Submit CAD')")
              .prop("disabled", true);
```

Hope it works